# Android-Studio:exclude dependencies from the build process to not get them into the final apk?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I need to prevent Android-Studio from exporting a certain shared library.

I´ve read that using the provided scope should work, but it seems that it not.Like this:

```
dependencies {
    provided 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    provided project(':DLlib')
}
```

My Module works as a plugin,I want to exclude support-v4 and DLlib library from the final apk!
Is there any other way to exclude dependencies from the build process to not get them into the final apk?

Comment: But the Support Library isn't `provided` - any calls will instantly crash your app if you don't include it...

Comment: Same question to me, any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the 'exclude' keyword

```
 compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+') {
     exclude module: 'support-v4'
 }
```

Comment: dependencies {
    compile('com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }} ——not work

Comment: You can comment out the line of the dependency, but i'm pretty sure that you need that library.

Comment: This project run as a plugin,its host has V4.so,I need to exclude that library

Comment: Then, the "provided" keyword must work. How do you know that it's including it in your plugin?

Comment: @Joyce : Hi ... did you find any solution on this ?